# NoSuchDriverException trying to use chromedriver for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
def main():
    driver:str='d:\python\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver'
    browser = Browser(driver=driver)

# Scrape the e-mails
URL=input(f"Enter the URL")

emails: set = browser.scrape_emails(URL)

# Display the e-mails
for i, email in enumerate(emails, start=1):
    print(i, email, sep=': ')
```

My Browser class looks like this:

```
class Browser:
"""Create a browser that scrapes any url for e-mail addresses"""

# Initialize the webdriver with the path to chromedriver.exe
    def __init__(self, driver: str):
        print('Starting up browser...')
        self.chrome_options = Options()
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Prevents the browser from showing
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

        self.service = Service(driver)
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.service, options=self.chrome_options)

    def scrape_emails(self, url: str) -> set:
        print(f'Scraping: "{url}" for emails')
        self.browser.get(url)
        page_source: str = self.browser.page_source

        # Create a set to avoid duplicates
        list_of_emails: set = set()
        for re_match in re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, page_source):
        list_of_emails.add(re_match.group())

        return list_of_emails

    def close_browser(self):
      print('Closing browser...')
      self.browser.close()
```

This gave an error:

> raise NoSuchDriverException(f"Unable to locate or obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']}")
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to locate or obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the python package [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to simplify the management of the binary drivers.

```bash
pip install selenium
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Then, instead of hardcode the driver path use this package to handle it:

For selenium 3

```py
# selenium 3
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options)
```

For Selenium 4

```py
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```