# ChromeDriver version is incompatible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I attempted to create an automated popcat.click program to increase the site's score. However, Chrome started and immediately shut down, and the following error occurred.

```
PS C:\Users\Ellen\Downloads> & C:/Users/Ellen/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/Users/Ellen/Downloads/popcat.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:2904/devtools/browser/41c450ae-985d-4b06-bc4e-013701ad43c0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ellen\Downloads\popcat.py", line 12, in <module>
    bs = webdriver.Chrome(options=co)
  File "C:\Users\Ellen\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Ellen\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Ellen\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Ellen\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Ellen\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Ellen\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.188 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007DA813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0076C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00675358]
        (No symbol) [0x006961AC]
        (No symbol) [0x00691EF3]
        (No symbol) [0x00690579]
        (No symbol) [0x006C0C55]
        (No symbol) [0x006C093C]
        (No symbol) [0x006BA536]
        (No symbol) [0x006982DC]
        (No symbol) [0x006993DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A3AABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A7A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A7456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008651E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x00775F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00772328]
        (No symbol) [0x0077240B]
        (No symbol) [0x00764FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x770F00C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77237B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77237AEE+238]
```

Here's all of code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

co = Options()
co.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
co.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
co.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
co.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

bs = webdriver.Chrome(options=co)
bs.get("https://popcat.click/")

while True:
    bs.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div').click()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

I accessed the ChromeDriver site, downloaded version 116... and ran it, but it didn't work

Comment: Does the chrome driver match the version of your Chrome browser? For example, I just opened mine and it said "Version 116.0.5845.188 (Official Build) (64-bit)", then immediately updated and now its "Chrome is up to date
Version 117.0.5938.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)". Chrome updates often and the driver you use has to be for the exact version of the browser it was made for. If your chrome just updated and your using an older driver, it likely won't work.

Comment: I just updated Chrome. The version is now 117.0.5938.89, and I downloaded and ran the file for Windows 64-bit from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your not the only one going through this issue today, apparently. Check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77119562/nosuchdriverexception-trying-to-use-chromedriver-for-selenium) post from this morning, Maybe that will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically download the appropriate driver in code. The installation process will download the driver version that matches your installed Chrome browser version:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeService, ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())

with Chrome(options=options, service=service) as driver:
    print(service.path) # this is where the driver is located
```

**Note:**

ChromeOptions isn't necessary for this but is a typical setup

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to upgrade selenium to a version >4.10

Then, `Service` will automatically download the latest chromedriver (116....).

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

Comment: The latest driver version is not 116 - it's 117

Answer (score 0):

You can find version of chromedriver that support chrome 117 here https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Answer (score -1):

Bro You should download the Driver version which is your chrome is
Step 1 :- get the your chrome version
Open Chrome.
Click the three dots in the top right corner.
Hover over Help.
Click About Google Chrome.
Your Chrome version will be displayed on the right side of the screen.

Step 2 :- Get the Same Version of Chrome Driver As your Browser Version

**Then this Error will Solve.
Your Browser Version is 116.0.5845.188 download the same version**
**Make Shure Each Number is the Same as the Version Number Other Wise It May Not Work**